# How do I perform runtime type validation and DI using FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have some code that works with runtime types, via `Type`. The objects themselves are of type `object`. What I need is the ability to use DI (Autofac, in my case) to inject an `IValidator` that represents *all* potential types, one way or another.

I also want to use that validator object to perform validation on objects of type `object`, and with only a runtime type.

Is this possible with FluentValidation? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
// How I register FluentValidation with Autofac
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IValidator<>))
    .As<IValidator>();

// An example class demonstrating what I'm trying to do
public class MyValidationService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public MyValidationService(IEnumerable<IValidator> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public bool IsTypeValid(Type typeOfInstance, object instance)
    {
        // How do I validate `instance`?
    }
}
```

I know that `IValidator` has a `CanValidateInstancesOfType()` method, so I suppose I could search for the first validator for which this returns `true`. But then `IValidator.Validate()` requires a `IValidationContext`, which only has a single implementation named `ValidationContext` that works with *generic* (compile-time) types; not runtime types. So I hit a dead-end with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to get a closed instance of `ValidationContext<>` and with validation call the `Validate` method.

Something like this:

```cs
public bool IsTypeValid(Type typeOfInstance, object instance) {        
    foreach (var validator in _validators
            .Where(_ => _.CanValidateInstancesOfType(typeOfInstance))) {
        var openType = typeof(ValidationContext<>);
        var closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeOfInstance);
        var validationContext = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType, instance);
        var validateMethod = validator.GetType().GetMethod("Validate", new[] { closedType });
        var result = validateMethod!.Invoke(validator, new[] { validationContext })
            as ValidationResult;
        if (!result.IsValid) {
            return false; 
        }                            
    }
    return true;
}
```